# NSInvalidArgumentException using Vungle when Unity app starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, vungle-ads

I built a Unity project using Vungle ads and when I build the project for iOS and try to run I get a NSInvalidArgumentException in a Vungle Network Manager call. Does anybody know how to solve this?

This is the error:

```
Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: -[VNGNetworkManager configOperationWithBackgroundInit:complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x129ee6110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with the Vungle lib.

Adding `GameController.framework` to **General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries** and `-ObjC` flag to **Build Settings -> Linking -> Other linker flags** fixed the problem.

Comment: Its the missing `-ObjC` in other linker flags. Nothing to do with `GameController.framework`